# ¿Como ir a un tab especifico con Jquery, framework7?

Tags: jquery, framework7

Buen día.
Tengo la siguiente estructura html de tabs en una vista `"inicio.html"`

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab active">
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab">
</div>
<div id="formaentregaPedido" class="tab">
</div>
```

para movilizarme de tab en tab utilizo la siguiente función:
Ejemplo:

```
myApp.showTab("#tab-2", true);
```

Pero al cambiar de pantalla `"otrapantalla.html"`  y luego regreso a `"inicio.html"`, quiero poder iniciar directamente en el tab con `id="formaentregaPedido"`

Como podría realizar esto.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: si siempre quieres ir a la misma tab al acceder  a la pagina, entonces en `pageload` pon ese codigo para que se muestre automaticamente la que quieres. Si no es siempre la misma, y es por ejemplo la ultima visitada, puedes guardar una variable en localStorage o similar para que vaya a esa

Comment: por que jquery? el mismo te puede mover de una pagina a otra. que version usas?